# How to determine if a `PHINode` is affected by a `if` branch

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

In `llvm`, a `PHINode` occurs when a variable assignment can not be determined statically. When `PHINode` occurs, I want to if the assignment in the `PHINode` is determined by a given `if` branch. For the three example below, the value of `x` in the first two is control-dependence on the value of `config`, but the third example does not.

[image]

### Extended question

using `PHINode->getIncomingBlock(i)` can get the `i`th incoming basic block of the PHINode. The question is: does the edge imply by "incoming" must be an edge in CFG? or it may be a pure new edge.

Thanks！

Comment: The word "Incoming" implies that there exists a branch, switch, invoke etc. instruction that can jump to the block in question. Nothing more. The instruction may be a simple unconditional branch.

Comment: The other part of your question seems to be "given an unspecified mapping from a C-like language to IR, how can I distinguish these two examples from that third?" and even trying to answer that is too much effort for me, sorry. I mean, I can guess what the mapping ought to be, but I have a really difficult bug of my own to solve today and no taste for guesswork. Use IR, not C, if you want to reason about branches and phi nodes.

Answer (score 1):

My current version of rule:

```
there exist a successor of “if(config)” that dominate 
at least one but not all predecessors of PHI-instruction
```